# Change title in span tag based on div name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of a problem I cant figure out.

I have a slideshow on my page using jquery.

```
<div id="carousel">
    <div id="round">
       <div class="box box-sec">
           <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="_includes/images/carousel/sample1.jpg"></a>
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>
                  Peace of Mind  <span>at the best rate possible...</span>
                  <a href="#">Click here for more</a>
                </p>
              </div>
        </div>
       <div class="box box-easy">
            <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="_includes/images/carousel/sample1.jpg"></a>
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>
                  Peace of Mind  <span>at the best rate possible...</span>
                  <a href="#">Click here for more</a>
                </p>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box competitive">
            <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="_includes/images/carousel/sample1.jpg"></a>
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>
                  Peace of Mind  <span>at the best rate possible...</span>
                  <a href="#">Click here for more</a>
                </p>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box personal">
            <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="_includes/images/carousel/sample1.jpg"></a>
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>
                  Peace of Mind  <span>at the best rate possible...</span>
                  <a href="#">Click here for more</a>
                </p>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box business">
            <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="_includes/images/carousel/sample1.jpg"></a>
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>
                  Peace of Mind  <span>at the best rate possible...</span>
                  <a href="#">Click here for more</a>
                </p>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box affiliate">
            <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="_includes/images/carousel/sample1.jpg"></a>
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>
                  Peace of Mind  <span>at the best rate possible...</span>
                  <a href="#">Click here for more</a>
                </p>
              </div>
        </div>
       <div class="arrows">
        <div class="next"><span>Test</span><img src="_includes/images/icons/rarr.png" /></div>
        <div class="prev"><span>Test</span><img src="_includes/images/icons/larr.png" /></div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

only 1 slide is active at a time, I want to somehow find the name of the next div, and write that into the "Test" span tags so that it shows up on hover and if clicked the span tag will then get the name of the next div and update itself, does this make sense? thanks

---

ADDED FIDDLE 
http://jsfiddle.net/TNRMk/

---

Ive tried this with no luck

```
$('.arrows').click(function() {
        $(".next span").html($('.roundabout-in-focus').next().attr('name'));
        $(".prev span").html($('.roundabout-in-focus').prev().attr('name'));
    });
```

Comment: can u jsfiddle code with jquery

Comment: What is _the name_ ? You want to content of the div in the span tag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good start for you:

```
$("div.arrows div").bind("mouseover", function() {
    $("div.arrows div.next").children("span").text($("div.roundabout-in-focus").next("div").attr("class"));
    $("div.arrows div.prev").children("span").text($("div.roundabout-in-focus").prev("div").attr("class"));
});
```

A number of points to be made:

1. This will not work for the prev arrow when the first item is selected.
2. I wasn't sure which part of the class name you wanted so you will need to do some modification
3. It needs to be on hover, or in the plugin itself as there are other ways to control the carousel. So setting on click won't work all the time.

Answer (score 2):

The plugin provides callbacks `btnNextCallback` and `btnPrevCallback` that are executed after clicking the "next"/"prev" buttons are clicked.

The current focused item has the class `.roundabout-in-focus`.

I have made this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Z88Z8/)** for you to see (all you div have the same content so I've replaced it for the sake of the example).

---

Here's the (commented) code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function updatePrevNextTitle() {

        // as this function is used as a callback for the plugin
        // 'this' is the roundabout wrapper div

        var $wrapper= $(this),

            // get the currently focused div
            $frontDiv = $wrapper.find('.roundabout-in-focus'),

            // get the next/prev div content relative to the focused div
            // also handle the circular roundabout by checking if 
            // .next() and .prev() return something, otherwise
            // get .first() and .last()
            nextContent = $frontDiv.next().length
                            ? $frontDiv.next().find('.carousel-caption').html()
                            : $frontDiv.first().find('.carousel-caption').html(),
            prevContent = $frontDiv.prev().length
                            ? $frontDiv.prev().find('.carousel-caption').html()
                            : $frontDiv.last().find('.carousel-caption').html();

        $wrapper.find('.next span').html(nextContent);
        $wrapper.find('.prev span').html(prevContent);
    };

    $('#round').roundabout({
        childSelector: 'div.box',
        btnNext: ".next",
        btnPrev: ".prev",
        // set the method updatePrevNextTitle as the callback handler
        btnNextCallback: updatePrevNextTitle,
        btnPrevCallback: updatePrevNextTitle
    }
    // set it also as the 'initialized' callback for the
    // initial setting of the prev/next span text
    ,updatePrevNextTitle);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add an active class in your selected div:

```
//e.g. after the selection event occurs:
$('div').click(function() { 
  $(this).addClass('active'); //keep track which div is clicked with the active class

  //read the class name of the next sibling and store it in test (if i got it right)
  $(".Test").html($('.active').next().attr('class'));
});
```

Maybe not 100% right but can give you a headstart!

Comment: Ive tried this with no luck...
 $('.arrows').click(function() {
         $(".next span").html($('.roundabout-in-focus').next().attr('class'));
   $(".prev span").html($('.roundabout-in-focus').prev().attr('class'));
  });

Answer (score 0):

According to your jsfiddle the name attribute is missing on your roundabouts,
try this instead:

```
$('.arrows').click(function() {
    $(".next span").html($('.roundabout-in-focus').next().find('.carousel-caption').html());
    $(".prev span").html($('.roundabout-in-focus').prev().find('.carousel-caption').html());
});
```